# How to correctly get info from JSON?

Tags: php, json

I use this to retrieve data from url in JSON:

```
$apiUrl = "https://api.uphold.com/v0/ticker/UPXAU";
$upxau_rates = file_get_contents($apiUrl);
if($upxau_rates !== false){
 $upxau_rates_res = json_decode($upxau_rates);
}

foreach($upxau_rates_res as $upxau_rates_item)
{
if($upxau_rates_item->pair == "UPXAU-USD")
    {
    $usd_rate = $upxau_rates_item->ask; 
    }
}
```

JSON from api have this structure:

```
[{
  "ask": "0.27226",
  "bid": "0.27226",
  "currency": "USD",
  "pair": "AEDUSD"
},
{
  "ask": "0.02675",
  "bid": "0.02675",
  "currency": "USD",
  "pair": "ARSUSD"
},
{
  "ask": "0.72624",
  "bid": "0.72624",
  "currency": "USD",
  "pair": "AUDUSD"
},
...
```

So, this works fine. But I want to get information about 'ask rate' without 'foreach' and 'if'. For example:

```
$apiUrl = "https://api.uphold.com/v0/ticker/UPXAU";
    $upxau_rates = file_get_contents($apiUrl);
    if($upxau_rates !== false){
     $upxau_rates_res = json_decode($main_currency);
    }
    echo $upxau_rates_res['pair']['UPXAU-USD']['ask'];
```

But this short way not work. How can I get info such short way?

Comment: Unfortunately, the json isn't built that way. The pair is in the same array level as the ask. Without rebuilding the array, it can't be done

Comment: Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decode as an array and then index on `pair` to access it that way.  To index all and access `ask`:

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
echo array_column($array, null, 'pair')['AEDUSD']['ask'];
```

Or to just index the `ask` on `pair`:

```
echo array_column($array, 'ask', 'pair')['AEDUSD'];
```

To be able to use all of them:

```
$array = array_column($array, null, 'pair');
echo $array['AEDUSD']['ask'];
```